# TinyMCE and foreach loops

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, foreach, tinymce

I have been using TinyMCE without issue for the last year, but now I am trying to use an IEnumerable View page with TinyMCE so I am using ForEach loops to display my data. The issue is TinyMCE doesn't display - my content appears on the page but not within the TinyMCE window. Here is a snippet of code for an example.

View Code

```
foreach (var t in Model.Where(t => t.HeaderId == ViewBag.headerId))
        {
            if (t.HeaderBody == null)
            {
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(item => t.GuideBody)
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(item => t.HeaderBody)

                </div>
            }

        }
```

I opened Chrome Dev tools to see what is happening and for some reason the field Id that is passed is being changed and I am not sure why and how to fix the problem. My best guess is that TinyMCE can't read anonymous parameter. I have properly applied attributes to properties in model.

Can someone help? Greatly appreciate it.

UPDATE Added Model below:

```
namespace LibraryMVC4.Models
{
    public class guides : dbindex
    {
        [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
        public string GuideBody { get; set; }
        [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
        public string HeaderBody { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Added Controller below:

```
public ActionResult EditGuide(int id, int headerId = 0)
        {
            GetHeaderBody(id, headerId);

            var getMyGuide = _guideRepository.GetGuideTabs(id);

            if (headerId != 0)
            {
                ViewBag.headerId = headerId;
            }

            return View(getMyGuide);
        }
```

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls  -  its generating inputs with duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html) and duplicate `name` attributes which have no relationship to your model and will not bind. You need a `for` loop, or better, use a custom `EditorTemplate` for your model. And you will not be able to use a `if (t.HeaderBody == null)` statement - your indexers will be non consecutive and again binding would fail (filter the collection in the controller before you pass it to the view). You need to show the code showing how you attache the plugin to the elements.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I thought about the for loop. I'll take a look around for custom EditorTemplates that make use of the for loop. Appreciate it.

Comment: No your not understanding. If you have an `EditorTemplate` (which you write yourself), then you do not use a loop (its one or the other). Impossible to help any further without seeing your model and your scripts

Comment: Strange what about this example I found http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm I'll add model in a bit.

Comment: Yes, exactly - you create an `EditorTemplate` for your model - e.g. `@model yourModel @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.GuideBody) @Html.EditorFor(m=> m.HeaderBody)` and then in the view you use `@Html.EditorFor(m=> m)` to generate the html for each item in the collection (i.e. no loops)